# pentaho data integration dynamic file name

Tags: pentaho, kettle

New to PDI here. Need to output data from a view in a postgresql database to a file daily. The output file will be like xxxx_20160427.txt, so need to append the dynamic date in the file name. How to do it?

EDIT-----------------

I was not clear here by asking how to add dynamic date, I was trying to add not just date but optional other parts to the file name. E.g adding a serial no (01) at the end: xxxx_2016042701.txt etc. So my real question is how to make a dynamic file name? In other ETL tool e.g. SSIS it will be a simple expression. Not sure how it is done in PDI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a dynamic filename variable with a Modified Java Script value STEP.

[image]

and then in the Text File Output STEP click on "Accept file name from field", and select your variable declared from previous step (filename_var on this example).

[image]

Comment: Can you give more detail on the step Modified java script?

Comment: ok, i updated my answer, with more detailed explanation on js step

Answer (score 3):

In your `Text file output` step, simply check "Include date in filename?" under the files tab.

Comment: I have seen that option, that solves the date part, but not enough, I have updated my question.

Comment: Yes, in this case, @Jipipayo's solution should work.